# Which approach best to use between making call api in component or action in Vuex

Tags: vuex

I am wondering about where i should making call api.

Approach 1:
 Call in component and handle sync then commit to Vuex.

Approach 2:
 Dispatch from component and call api in action then commit Vuex.

So, Which approach best to use between making call api in component or Vuex ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think both methods are acceptable and it boils down to personal preference.

My personal preference would be **Approach 1.** where I make use of the `created()` lifecycle method to call the API and return the data in the Vue component itself.

After which, I would then dispatch the relevant data to the Vuex state using `actions` and `mutations`.